# The Riemann surface of $w^{2} \ =\text{sin} \ z$ in $ \mathbb{C}^{2}$ is not the interior of a compact surface-with-boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $X$ be the Riemann surface of $w^{2} \ =\text{sin} \ z$ in $ \mathbb{C}^{2}$, i.e. let $X = \{(z,w): w^2 = \text{sin} \ z\}$.

The Riemann surface structure on $X$ is obtained by paramertizing by $z$ at all places where $w \ne 0$ and parametrizing by $w$ at places where $w=0$.

The question is to show is not the interior of a compact surface-with-boundary.

---

My attempt:

Consider the holomorphic function $\displaystyle F:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $\displaystyle F:( z,w)\rightarrow w$.
Now assume there is a compact surface-with-boundary $\displaystyle \tilde{X}$ such that interior of $\displaystyle \tilde{X}$ is $\displaystyle X$.
It is natural to expect that $\displaystyle F$ extends to an holomorphic function $\displaystyle \tilde{F} :\tilde{X} \ \rightarrow \mathbb{C} P^{1}$.

Now observe $\displaystyle \tilde{F}^{-1}( 0)$ has a limit point as it contains an infinite sequence $\displaystyle \{( n\pi ,0)\}_{n=1}^{\infty }$ in $\displaystyle \tilde{X}$. Holomorphicity of $\displaystyle \tilde{F}$ forces $\displaystyle \tilde{F} $ to be a constant.

This is a contradiction as $\displaystyle F$ is not constant.

The issue with this proof is that there is no reason to believe that $\displaystyle F$ should have an extension $\displaystyle \tilde{F}$.

Comment: Just asking: How much topology is at your disposal, e.g., is it known that a complex Riemann surface has finite genus, while the Riemann surface $w^2=\sin z$ has arbitrarily many handles/linearly-independent holomorphic one-forms?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, no, I do not know of the fact that a Riemann surface has finite genus. 
1. Could you provide a reference for the above fact?
2. Why does $w^2=\sin z$ have infinitely many linearly-independent holomorphic 1-forms? 
3. What is the correspondence between holomorphic 1-forms and handles?

Comment: May I ask what is the definition of a compact (Riemann?) surface with boundary? Does it mean that there is a Riemann surface $Y$ such that $\tilde{X}$ is a compact domain of $Y$ and $\partial \tilde{X}$ is a piecewise smooth curve?

Comment: I was trying to get a sense of what tools you have available (e.g., branch cuts, genus, ...). The deeper question concerns your definitions (as onriv asks) and background. Is this a problem for a course? If so, is there a textbook? What are the course prerequisites?

Comment: Did you understand the answer?

Comment: @onriv, **(1).** From what I understand from Donaldson's book on Riemann surfaces, a "compact Riemann surface with boundary" is a compact smooth surface with boundary whose interior is a Riemann surface. **(2).** What do you mean by "$\tilde{X}$ is a compact domain of $Y$"? Do you mean $\tilde{X}$ is a compact subset of $Y$? If this is the case, then your definition is natural. **(3).** Why do expect $\partial \tilde{X}$ to have only one connected component? PS. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, this is a problem from Donaldson's book on Riemann Surfaces. Tools such as branched covers, Riemann-Hurwitz, and holomorphic 1-forms are all available to me. The book presents this problem in the chapter introducing k-forms, $\partial$ operator etc. PS. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092074/

Answer (score 2):

The thing to prove is that the surface $X$ has infinite topological type. Instead of your function $F$, I will consider the function $g(z,w)=z$ on $X$, which is (generically) 2-to-1. Critical values of this function are $z_n=\pi n$, $n\in {\mathbb Z}$ (the zeroes of the function $\sin(z)$).

Consider a sequence of closed disks
$$
D_n=\bar{D}(0, \pi n + \frac{\pi}{2})\subset {\mathbb C},
$$
each containing $2n+1$ critical values of the function $g$ and no critical values on the boundary. Let $X_n:= g^{-1}(D_n)$. Then each $X_n$ has one boundary component (see below). Each critical value of $g$ will have exactly one preimage in $X$. By the Riemann-Hurwitz  formula,
$$
\chi(X_n)= 2\chi(D_n) - 2n-1= 1-2n. 
$$
Since $\partial X_n$ is connected, it follows that the genus of $X_n$ is $n$. (This calculation also shows that $\partial X_n$ cannot consist of 2 components and, since $g$ is 2-to-1, the higher number of boundary components is impossible.) Hence, $X$ has infinite genus and, therefore, is not homeomorphic to the interior of a compact surface.

Comment: **(1).** What definition of genus are you using? Is your definition $g = 1-\chi(X)/2$? The reason I ask is because I usually think of a genus $g$ surface as a connected sum of $g$ many tori. But here, since $X_n$ is a manifold-with-boundary, it is not a connected sum of tori.
**(2).** Why is $\chi(X) = \lim_{n} \chi(X_n)$? (Do we take triangulations of $X_n$ and take some sort of limit of that?) 
**(3).** Why does a compact Riemann surface with boundary have a finite genus? **PS.** Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: 1. The definition of genus is in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760388/nonorientable-surfaces-genus-or-demigenus/763726#763726), it works equally well when there is boundary (but you will assume that curves are disjoint from the boundary), just the formula relating genus and Euler characteristic will involve the number of boundary components, $\chi=2-2g-b$ (which is not a definition but a theorem). 2. I do not use this formula but it is an interesting exercise to prove it using triangulations. 3. Use the formula relating genus and Euler characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use some other way to prove that the Riemann surface $X=\{(z,w):w^2=\sin z\}$ has infinite genus, as shown in the answer of Kohan's. The main result I wanna to show is that:

> For any positive integer $n$, there is closed, compactly supported, smooth 1-forms $\theta_1, \theta_2, \cdots, \theta_n$ (not required to be holomorphic) that is linear independent over $\Bbb{R}$, i.e. if $a_1 \theta_1 + \cdots + a_n \theta_n = \mathrm{d}u$ for some smooth function $u$, then $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

And the main proposition to use is that(It's Proposition 15 in Chapter 5 in Donaldson's *Riemann Surfaces*, Section II.3.3 in Farkas&Kra's *Riemann Surfaces*, and Formula 6.71 in Page 289 in Kodaira's *Complex analysis*):

> **Proposition 15** For any loop $\gamma$ in $X$, there is a compactly supported 1-form $\theta$ such that for any closed smooth compactly supported 1-form $\phi$,
>
> $$\int_\gamma \phi = \int_X \theta \wedge\phi
> $$

All references explain this result in details. Mainly it's using partition of unity to construct a smooth function $\rho_\gamma^+$ on $X-\gamma$ and taking $\mathrm{d} \rho_\gamma^+$ as $\theta$.

Furthermore, for this 1-form $\theta$ associated to the curve $\gamma$, if $\delta$ is some other loop does not intersect the support of $\theta$ (the support of $\theta$ is near $\gamma$, it can be shown from the construction of $\theta$), then $\int_\delta\theta = 0$. And if $\delta$ intersects $\gamma$ once, then $\int_\delta\theta = 1$ (from one direction, from the other direction it's $-1$).

With this proposition, using the loops as follow: (sorry for the poor drawing, the black loops are in the $u-x$ plane, but the red loops are in the $v-y$ plane, where $w=u+iv$ and $z=x+iy$. For the loop $\gamma_0$, imagine that $z$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, then $w$ goes from $0$ to $1$ and back to $0$, and the opposite direction is similar. I attached the picture that projecting $z=\mathrm{arcsin}(w^2)$ to the $u$ coordinate to help the illustration.)
[image]

[image]

Then for each $\gamma_n$, there is an associated closed smooth compactly supported 1-form $\theta_n$. The set $\{\theta_n\}$ is linear independent over $\Bbb{R}$:

Suppose $a_1 \theta_1 + \cdots a_n \theta_n = 0$, applying the loop $\delta_0$ to it (integrating it on $\delta_0$), we get $a_1 = 0$ since $\delta_0$ only intersects $\gamma_1$. Similarlly $a_i = 0$ for all other $i$.

Hence $X$ cannot be the interior of a compact surface-with-boundary.(It's not required to be a Riemman surface. The argument doesn't use any condition of being holomorphic)

Comment: I have a few questions: **(1).** You say, "if $\delta$ intersects $\gamma$ once, then $\int_{\delta} \theta = 1$". Could you explain why this is the case? **(2).** You don't seem to have defined $\delta_0$. **(3).** By obtaining arbitrarily large independent closed 1-forms we get the 1st de Rham cohomology group doesn't have a finite dimension and I suppose this gives a contradiction. Why does a compact manifold-with-boundary have finite dimensional 1st de Rham cohomology group?

Comment: (3) I think is achieved by attaching disks long the boundary (Only works for surface maybe, I don't know for general manifolds with dimension > 1 it works or not.) It's from that that the only compact 1-dimension manifold is the loop $S^1$ and boundary of compact surface-with-boundary is the union of finitely many 1-dimension manifolds. These operations can be done in the smooth or holomorphic context too.(Details skipped, maybe you can ask another question for attaching disks to compact topological/smooth/Riemann surface to get a surface without boundary and I will see if I can answer it.)

Comment: (3) has to use the fact those $\theta_i$ is compactly support too. By being compactly support, those $\theta_i$  can be constructed to be linearly independent closed 1-forms in the constructed surface-without boundary, by multiplying sums of some bump functions maybe.

Comment: (2) the $\delta_0$ corresponds to the curve that $z$ moves from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, then $sin(z)$ moves from $0$ to $-1$ and back to $0$. And $w$ moves from $0$ to $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and back to $0$. For the other half, $w$ moves from $0$ to $-i$ and back to $0$. In the illustration the red loops (those $\delta_i$) and the black loops is kind of perpendicular.

Comment: (1) first chooses a locally finite open covering and a partition of unity subordinate to the open covering. The path $\gamma$ split the union of those open sets that cross  $\gamma$ into two connected region $U$ and $V$(two side of the loop intuitively). And then we can take $\rho_\gamma^{+}(p)$ to be the sum of those partitions crossing $\gamma$ and take differential of it. Some more details I think in Kodaira's Complex analysis, Theorem 7.2, or Farkas&Kra's Riemann Surfaces, Section II.3.8. Maybe you can ask a question about this too(Too long for this in a comment.)